# Fazer texto aparecer embaixo de caixa

Tags: html, css, animação

Eu tenho uma caixa de animação X3D

```
<X3D> ..... </X3D>
<p> ..... </p>
```

e quero que o texto apareça por baixo desta, em vez disto:
[image: http://i.gyazo.com/e053cffdcc28b4abf1e772f62b084857.png]

Como é que faço? Obrigado.

Comment: Faça o conteúdo dessa tag `<X3D` ocupar 100% de `width` nas CSS.

Comment: Como está o CSS disso? Tem algo flutuado?

Answer (score 2):

Coloca nos dois elementos `display: block` que eles vão ficar um embaixo do outro.

Comment: Porque o voto para remoção? A resposta está certa, só faltou talvez um exemplo final do CSS.